# Can't compile because supposedly there are duplicate libraries in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Here is my build.gradle (app)

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chattr.chattr"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
```

for some reason, I cannot compile my app for a release version, or any other version for that matter. In other posts, people say that I have a duplicate library being compiled but I cannot see the duplicate anywhere here. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please check your libs folder and see what jar files are in there.

Comment: All I have are a sinch and parse lib

Comment: What errors do you get? Post your build log output.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the Parse API.
You need to modify your dependencies in gradle file to make
sure that only Parse and sinch will be included .

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['Parse-*.jar','sinch*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicate library being compiled,maybe it's because your dependent library has contained the jar which is 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+' or 
'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'.
you should check settings.grade,look at something like this "**include** ':library', ':samples'".check whether the library contains the jar.
hope it's useful to you